How to Define Equipment Churn in Laboratory Service Data Without Explicit Churn Labels?
I'm working with a comprehensive dataset spanning 20 years of service records for laboratory equipment owned by various customers. This dataset captures intricate details, such as the equipment ID, service date, type of equipment (HOOD_TYPE), and the specific service performed (TASK_DESCRIPTION). Notably, the dataset reflects a broad spectrum of laboratory equipment, each subject to different service intervals—ranging from multiple services annually to biennial servicing.
A unique challenge we face is the absence of explicit labels indicating equipment churn (i.e., equipment no longer in use or requiring service). Our goal is to infer potential churn from the patterns and frequencies within the service data. A prolonged period without service or a notable decline in service frequency is presumed to signal churn, yet quantifying or defining this threshold remains elusive.
Data Characteristics:
Records: Each log details the equipment ID, service date, and the type of service.
Service Frequency Variability: There's considerable variation in how frequently different equipment types receive service.
Equipment Types: The dataset includes various types of laboratory equipment, each with its distinct servicing needs and intervals.
Challenges:
Defining Equipment Churn: Lacking a definitive churn benchmark at the equipment level complicates the identification of churned equipment.
Data Labeling: The dataset does not straightforwardly facilitate labeling equipment as churned or active.
Questions:

What statistical methods or unsupervised learning models are best suited to detect churn patterns or indicators in this dataset?
Considering the diverse service frequency across equipment types, how can we accurately define churn?
Could techniques like survival analysis, clustering, or anomaly detection be applicable here? If so, how might they be tailored to our dataset's characteristics?

Additional Context and Attempts:
To better understand service patterns, I've analyzed service intervals using a BayesianGaussianMixture model. This analysis revealed distinct servicing intervals across different equipment, highlighting the complexity of defining a uniform churn indicator. For illustration, I performed a detailed histogram analysis with Gaussian mixture overlays on the service intervals for one service (Biosafety Cabinet Test) performed on one unit type (A2 Biosafety Cabinet) "Cleanroom" equipment. [![
Since I can't directly view or generate images, I'll provide you with a detailed description based on our discussion about the BayesianGaussianMixture model analysis for the HOOD_TYPE = A2 and TASK_DESCRIPTION = Biosafety Cabinet (A2) - Test. You can adjust this description to fit the actual appearance of your image:
The image presents a detailed histogram of service intervals for the equipment categorized under HOOD_TYPE = A2 with the specific TASK_DESCRIPTION = Biosafety Cabinet (A2) - Test. The histogram bins represent the distribution of days between successive service events, capturing the variability and patterns of maintenance frequency over an extensive dataset.
Overlaying the histogram are three Gaussian distributions, each denoted by a smooth, bell-shaped curve. These distributions were identified through a Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Model analysis.]1]1This approach aimed to visualize the distribution of service intervals and identify potential patterns indicative of equipment churn.
This image exemplifies the variability in service frequency, underscoring the challenges in establishing a one-size-fits-all churn definition.
Any insights, guidance on appropriate methodologies, or references to analogous studies would be immensely valuable. Thank you for your time and expertise!

After further exploring the dataset and experimenting with different methodologies, I've developed a nuanced approach that seems to effectively identify potential equipment churn from our service records. I thought it best to share my findings and the strategy I used as an answer to my initial question, hoping it might assist others tackling similar challenges.
Creating a Service Interval Threshold
A crucial part of this analysis involved calculating a "Service Interval Threshold" for every unique unit within each equipment-type and service combination. This threshold is defined as the 99.9th percentile of days between services, aiming to capture the maximum typical interval beyond which a service gap might indicate churn.

Calculation Method: The 99.9th percentile of DAYS_TO_PREVIOUS_INSTANCE was calculated not just across equipment types and services broadly, but specifically for each unique unit within those categories. This distinction is vital, as it tailors the analysis to the service history of individual units, ensuring the threshold accurately reflects the service interval variability inherent to each unit's experience.
Adjustments for Sparse Data: Recognizing the challenge of sparse data, especially for units with fewer service records, the methodology was adjusted to manage groups with insufficient data effectively. This ensures the approach remains robust and applicable across varied dataset segments.
Resulting Dataframe: These calculated percentiles were then merged into a new DataFrame, service_interval_analysis, which now serves as an enriched resource, detailing actionable service interval thresholds for each unit-service combination.

Defining Equipment Churn
With these thresholds in place, I defined equipment churn as follows:

Churn per Service: If a unit has received a particular service at least once before, and the time elapsed since the last instance of that service exceeds the calculated service interval threshold for that specific unit and service combination, the unit is considered to have churned for that service.
Overall Churn: A unit is deemed to have churned overall if it meets the churn criteria for each type of service it has received.

Implications and Next Steps
This methodology offers a strategic way to monitor and potentially preempt equipment churn by recognizing when service intervals deviate significantly from established norms. It paves the way for targeted engagement strategies, tailored to the specific service patterns and needs of each unit.
By providing a detailed account of my approach, I hope to spark further discussion, gather feedback, and explore alternative strategies. Your insights or suggestions on enhancing this analysis would be greatly appreciated!

Embarking on this data exploration journey has unveiled the complexities hidden within our service records and offered a framework for interpreting them. I'm looking forward to the community's thoughts and any further discussions this might encourage.
